# Angular 2 with Freemarker and Spring

Tags: spring, angular, maven, freemarker

Can any one tell me, how to integrate Angular 4/2 with Spring,Maven,Freemarker(must).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why are you using Freemarker when you're trying to create a single page app? The only place where you'd be able to use it is `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

The one way I know is you can make your rest API and angular app separately.And u can access those rest API in your angular app.